# How to access stored commit data in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I have a Lucene 4.7 index where I need to store some meta data. I found, that the "commit data", which can be set during indexing via `IndexWriter.setCommitData(Map<String, String>)`, seems [the way to go](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Storing-a-serialized-object-td561410.html). However, I'm now stuck on how to access this data later on; it seems, that in previous versions it was possible to do so via the `IndexReader`, but I cannot find any suitable methods in version 4.7.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out; I need to use a `DirectoryReader` instead of the `IndexReader` interface. This provides the `DirectoryReader.getIndexCommit()` which in turn gives me the desired information via `IndexCommit.getUserData()`.